# Cauchy sequences over $\mathbb{Q}$: A basic question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Define an equivalence relation on Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ by $(x_n)\equiv (y_n)$ if $\lim (x_n-y_n)=0$.

The question I am trying to prove is that

> If $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $(x_n)(y_n)\equiv (0)$ then $(x_n)\equiv (0)$ or $(y_n)\equiv (0)$.

*Here, I am considering the problem only over $\mathbb{Q}$ and not considering anthing about $\mathbb{R}$.*

**Some part of proof:** Suppose $(x_n)\not\equiv (0)$. We show that $(y_n)\equiv (0)$.

Since $(x_n)\not\equiv (0)$, so $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence but its limit is not $0$.

Hence there is an $\epsilon>0$, such that for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$, there is $n_i$ such that $|x_{n_i}|\ge \epsilon$.

What this says is that infinitely many terms of $(x_n)$ are bounded away from $0$.

How to proceed now, to show that $(y_n)\equiv (0)$?

Answer (score 3):

> Hence there is an $\epsilon>0$, such that for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$, there is $n_i$ such that $|x_{n_i}|\ge \epsilon$.

Correct. You can use that and the fact that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence to get the even stronger statement that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n|\geq\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$. That makes it straightforward to show $y_n\rightarrow 0$.